# mysql join tables without keys

Tags: mysql, join

Basic question: How do I join 2 tables to get the following output?

```
Table1:
"type"
red
blue
big
small
```

===

```
Table2:
"object"
cat
person
chair
```

===

```
Output:
red cat 
blue cat
big cat
small cat
red person
blue person
big person
small person
red chair
blue chair
big chair
small chair
```

Comment: Since it is really a basic question, what have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Comment: +1 for including the `CROSS` keyword, but the use of `*` in the SELECT list is less desirable.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.type,' ',t2.object) as `Output:`
  FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table2 t2
```

(The keyword `CROSS` is optional in mysql, but it does serve to document that you intended a cartesian product, which can be useful information for the person who reads this statement, who would normally be expecting to see a join predicate.

If you need the result set returned in a particular order, include an `ORDER BY` clause. It's a relatively complicated expression to get it sorted in the order shown, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_combine(table1, table2);
```

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) is a link for more information.

Comment: This works for arrays in PHP, but doesn't work for getting a result set from tables in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Cartesian product I guess:

```
SELECT t1.type, t2.object FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
```