# MYSQL Join Tables without key / index

Tags: mysql, sql, join

like the title says, i want to join 2 Tables without a key to compare.

[mysql join tables without keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056509/mysql-join-tables-without-keys)

This example descripes the initial situation, but he is looking for the cartesian product.
I want something like this

```
Table 1: t1
red
blue
big
small


Table 2: t2
cat
dog
person
```

The result should look like this:

```
red cat
blue dog
big person
small NULL <--- can be empty (not shown)
```

Is something like this possible just with sql?

Comment: So match any row in one table with any row in the other?

Comment: try use a ke to join otherwise its useless of joining tables, if so just use single table to store data.

Comment: Rank the rows in both tables, join (possibly using a full outer join) on the ranking values. There's no native support in MySQL for either ranking or full joins but workarounds exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine two table having only one column in each table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933074/combine-two-table-having-only-one-column-in-each-table)

Comment: The result is not guaranteed to be the same every time because the order of rows is only guaranteed if you use ORDER BY.

Comment: Sry i forgot to add, that i don't care which combination of t1 col and t2 col will be the output. So no it is not duplicated to the post mentioned from @Roms

Comment: And yes the rusult depends on the ORDER BY @Vatev

Comment: @Roms That question is for sql-server, not MySQL. The answer uses features that MySQL doesn't have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since MySQL doesn't have a `ROW_ID()` function, you have to fake it with a user-variable that you increment:

```
select adjective, noun
from (select @counter1 := @counter1+1 as counter, adjective
      from table1, (select @counter1 := 0) init) t1
left join (select @counter2 := @counter2+1 as counter, noun
           from table2, (select @counter2 := 0) init) t2
using (counter)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab2ac/4)

Note that this assumes there are always more adjectives in table1 than nouns in table2. If you need to allow either table to be smaller, you need to use a `full outer join`. As Andriy M mentioned, MySQL doesn't have built-in support for this, but if you search SO or google you should find ways to code it.

Comment: Good job, this is what i was looking for :D. I didn't even know "using" exits

Comment: `USING (counter)` is just shorthand for `ON t1.counter = t2.counter`

Comment: yep, just reading the docu. One difference:

"select *" from a join with USING, the joining column only appears in the result set once. With ON, it appears twice.