# How to join table without key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to join table without key,

```
table 1
------------------------------
no           code      area
------------------------------
0122133666   MOB       012221
92444444     LOC       9244
0343443434   DDD       03434
0092635252   INF       92
------------------------------

table 2
------------------------------
code         area      name
------------------------------
MOB          012       mobile-1
MOB          0129      mobile-2
LOC          9244      local-1
LOC          9243      local-2
INF          92        country-1
DDD          034       local-2
DDD          0344      local-3
------------------------------
```

And I want result like this

```
------------------------------------
no           code      area      name
------------------------------------
0122133666   MOB       012221   mobile-1
92444444     LOC       9244     local-1
0343443434   DDD       03434    local-2
0092635252   INF       92       country-1
--------------------------------------
```

it looks like it is impossible to do that, anyone can help me ?

Comment: this is structured just ... terribly. please rewrite this question so it has any semblance of sense to it.

Comment: How do you associate Table1 to table2? Do you have some logic that links these tables/columns together?

Comment: You can do this. Basically check the substring of "area" to the first x digits of hte "no." Such as WHERE area=substr(no, 6)

Comment: it seems from your example, that you need an intersection of table1 & table2 based on the "code" column, which I'm afraid is not possible without a key (code).

Comment: @Shawn are you sure that will work?  If you look at `area = 012221` it will match on 2 rows in the other table if you use substring of but they only want to return one row.  It also looks like they want different substrings per row.

Comment: Have you looked at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269662/mysql-join-tables-without-key-index

Comment: @bluefeet good catch didn't see that, but then there is a larger architecture issue. Thats what happens with partially derived keys.

Answer (score 2):

This gives you the results you want:

```
SELECT  T1.no,
        T1.code,
        T1.area,
        T2.name
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
  ON T1.code = T2.code
  AND T1.area LIKE CONCAT(T2.area,'%')
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad89f/2) with a demo of this.

The results are:

```
╔═══════════╦══════╦════════╦═══════════╗
║    NO     ║ CODE ║  AREA  ║   NAME    ║
╠═══════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 122133666 ║ MOB  ║ 012221 ║ mobile-1  ║
║  92444444 ║ LOC  ║   9244 ║ local-1   ║
║ 343443434 ║ DDD  ║  03434 ║ local-2   ║
║  92635252 ║ INF  ║     92 ║ country-1 ║
╚═══════════╩══════╩════════╩═══════════╝
```